# grep search expression and rename file

Tags: sed, grep, perl

I have readable pdf files that all contain the string `VAX` followed by eight numbers, like `VAX00002885`.

Now I want to find that expression and rename the corresponding pdf to  `VAX00002885.pdf` (in this case).

How can I do this?

Comment: So is `VAX00002885` the name of the file, or a string found inside the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming GNU grep):

```
for pdf in *pdf; do
    mv "$pdf" "$(grep -aE 'VAX[0-9]*' "$pdf" | sed 's/.*\(VAX[0-9]*\).*/\1/)"
done
```

Note that this assumes only one instance of `VAXNNNNNNN`. If you can have more, use the first match only:

```
for pdf in *pdf; do
    mv "$pdf" "$(grep -m 1 -aE 'VAX[0-9]*' "$pdf" | sed 's/.*\(VAX[0-9]*\).*/\1/)"
done
```

Comment: @vloryan that might be because of the `-w` option. That causes grep to only match whole words. If the `VAXNNNNNNNN` is not surrounded by spaces it will fail. Sorry, force of habit, I updated the answer. Can you try again without the `-w`?

Comment: @vloryan ah, yes, that's why you should always mention your OS. OSX's `grep` doesn't have the `-P` option. Sorry, use the updated version instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Sorry for not mentioning my OS! I do still get the `mv: rename *pdf to : No such file or directory` error.

Comment: @vloryan I made one more edit which might help. If not, please add the output of `grep -aE 'VAX[0-9]*' foo.pdf`, (replacing `foo.pdf` with one of your pdf files) to your question. Also, make sure you are running this from the directory that contains your PDF files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17548/discussion-between-vloryan-and-terdon).

Comment: I guess I close this herewith. Thanks for your help, but I couldn't get this to run.